# Replacement for Ubiquiti AirWire power supply

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, cable

I have an "[Ubiquiti AirWire Plug 'n Play Wireless Ethernet Cord](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Z53K8Q)" That has been working perfectly for years. The other night, there was a lightning strike that blew up everything connected to a specific outlet. Unfortunately, this device was one of them. However, luckily only the power supply was dead. The actual device still works. So my only problem now is how to find the very specialized replacement power cable. Is this a standard kind of cable? If so, what is it called?

here is a picture of the cable I want to replace:[image]

**aditional information:** I'm not sure why the amazon page I linked to shows a USB type B input. Mine has an ethernet input on the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a datasheet that specifies, but given the evident era, the fact that it's 10/100 and Ubiquiti's design philosophy until recently, it's likely a **24V Passive PoE injector** (PoE = Power over Ethernet.) But you could easily contact [Ubiquiti support](https://dl.ubnt.com/guides/airwire/AirWire_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf) and ask. Or if you geek the right way you could measure voltage on (more like between) the blue and brown sets of wires on your working unit.

[This page](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Ubiquiti_Networks_airWire) suggests it's a 15V PoE supply

Current versions look a little different (two network ports that both use patch cables and an AC power cord) but should work the same if it's not an odd voltage. email support and inquire about that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion to email support. I will try that. The power supply has "15V" written on it, so it's definitely not 24 volts.

Comment: Then it's definitely 15 volts. Passive PoE is easy enough to kludge if you like that sort of thing - unlike the more recent protocols, there are no smarts to it - you pass the data wires (1,2,3,6) through to the LAN and apply the power to the "unused" wires (4,5,7,8) - specifics vary, but it's usually 4,5 one polarity, 7,8 the other, and the best bet to get the polarity right is to check the working one, as it can vary between vendors. 5,7 4,8 could happen, but is not as common. That and a generic 15V supply of adequate amperage will get you up and running.

Comment: thanks! that's helpful. That matches what the wires going to lan would suggest. I'll probably end up just buying a new supply anyway to avoid accidentally blowing up a $100 piece of equipment.

Comment: do you think this would work in place of the dead ac adapter? http://www.amazon.com/Ubiquiti-Poe-15-Output-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B002R7JPGE

Comment: Very probably yes.